# Access forbidden 403 to homepage but the rest of website working Drupal 7

Tags: 7, http-request

I have Drupal 7 installed in localhost, with XAMPP, and it is a replica of a complete working site. I think I have configured everything ok as I can see all the site working nice, with its friendly urls, multilanguage, multidomain, dozens of modules. But still the home page is not rendered, with an Apache error of forbidden. When I try to put site_name/index.php, it gives a 404 error, and the same trick in remote works rendering homepage!!

Any idea or suggestion on what could be happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For reasons of module SiteMap, I needed to have folders called en, es, fr, which coincides with the suffixes of the language switcher. This was causing some problem in XAMPP while not causing any problem in Linux version. I have renamed the folders and everything is ok now.

I suspect that having an URL as example.com/fr/ which renders the homepage in french is not a good idea if you have a directory, that, if Drupal were switched off, would point to a folder example.com/fr.